# Django app pointing to purged table on postgres

Tags: python, django, oracle, postgresql

I am working on Django application migration from oracle to Postgres. Before migration On oracle a new table was created and one existing table got deleted. Model was updated and Django app was able to recognize the change and has been working fine on oracle without any issue.

I have created a new VM and copied over the django application and updated the database connection from Oracle to Postgres. Connection is successfully established and everything looks good from the app side except one thing
; When i delete action from Admin site Django complains that it is unable to find the reference in the table that got deleted and doesn't exist anymore. I am clueless why Django is looking for the deleted table and not the new table however it works fine on oracle.

```
ProgrammingError: relation "model_actionreference" does not exist
LINE 1: ...model_actionreference"."category" FROM "model_...
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Without seeing any of your code, I would say, that you have a Model 'ActionReference' defined in your `Model` app which Django tries to access.

Comment: But the same code is working fine on another node with oracle; is there a difference in accessing two databases

Comment: I’d say there is no difference, but I don’t have any experience with django and oracle. I’d say it’s more likely that the codebase differs